# Как сделать из div-a ссылку?

Tags: jquery

Мне нужно, чтобы при клике на div(там на сайте целый блок), осуществлялся бы переход на другую страницу. Как это можно реализовать с помощью JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div').click(function(){        
    window.location.href = "http://...";
});
```

Comment: Круть. Спасибо!